# Log likelihood, aic and aicc values suggest different models should be selected

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, aic, phylogeny

I am trying to determine which evolutionary model is best for my discrete data using the function `fitDiscrete()` from the `geiger` package.

These are the values that I get for the number of parameters (`k`), maximum log likelihood (`lnL`), `AIC` and `AICc` for each model:

```r
     k   lnL        AIC       AICc
ER   1   -115.8006  233.6012  233.6637
ARD  90  -85.98459  351.9692  -303.2308
SYM  45  -97.23202  284.4640  491.464
```

The same dataset (n = 66), tree and single trait with 10 levels were used to create each model.  The only difference is the evolutionary model fitted (equal rates (`ER`), all rates different (`ARD`) and symmetrical rates (`SYM`))

I am having trouble interpreting these results, however.

To start, for `AIC`, I'm fairly sure that I should select the model with the smallest `AIC` score, i.e the `ER` model.

For `lnL`, however, I have seen that the model with the "largest value" should be selected with this being interpreted as the value closest to 0 (https://www.r-phylo.org/wiki/HowTo/Ancestral_State_Reconstruction), i.e. the `ARD` model.  I realise though that `lnL` values tend to be biased towards models with higher `k` values.  To address this, I did do a likelihood test as suggested by the website above (chi-squared test), which came to p < 0.001.  This would suggest that the `ARD` model should be preferred over the `ER` model, which contradicts what the `AIC` scores are telling me.

As for `AICc`, again, the "smallest value" should be selected but the negative sign mixed in with the positive ones has thrown me.  Is this the smallest absolute value or the value value closest to negative infinity?

So, all in all, how can I tell which model should be preferred?

Comment: How many degrees of freedom did you use in your chi-square test?  With 89 degrees of freedom, the difference between the ER and ARD log likelihoods doesn't look significant to me... And is the ER model nested in the ARD model?

Comment: I've had to double check the website above but the df should be the difference between the values for k so 89 here. The likelihood test is calculated through the following command (from the webiste above):  1-pchisq(2*abs(ER(lnL) - ARD(lnL)), 1).  ER should be nested in ARD but the code isn't clear: ER <- fitDiscrete(phy = lattree3, dat = f, model = "ER") and ARD <- fitDiscrete(phy = lattree3, dat = f, model = "ARD").  They contain the same variables but ARD is more complex so I'm going to guess ER is nested within.  Sorry I couldn't be more certain!  I'm very new to this!

Comment: The degrees of freedom of the chi-square test is the difference in the dimensionality of the parameters, in this case, 89:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27_theorem , the example should make it clear.  This should help reconcile the difference you are seeing!   ... so `pchisq(2*abs(ER(lnL) - ARD(lnL)), 89)`.

Comment: Ahh that would be it!  I've just tried it and it all works now!  I knew the df should be 89 but the example didn't specify where to insert that and I didn't realise that their model only had 1 df!  Thank you :)

Comment: The AICc value for ARD cannot be correct since AICc is always larger than the corresponding AIC.  The AICc adds an additional penalty for parameter number.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Modification_for_small_sample_size

Comment: Hi that's what I thought too so I calculated it by hand following the formula on the same wikipedia link as you sent and I arrived at the same result as what R got:
351.9692+(2*90*90+2*90)/(66-90-1) = -303.2308.  The number of parameters (k = 90) exceeds the number of observations (n = 66) hence the negative result.